# How to get a user input as a ID no and to see if it will complete the following requirements

Tags: java

National ID card number should be in one of the following formats

1. 9 digits followed by a capital or simple V or X letter (Ex: 923456789V)
2. Only 12 digits (Ex: 200551789012)

Comment: what have you tried so far? It would seem that two regex matchers would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex alternation along with `String#match`.  The following regex pattern matches either 9 digits followed by V or X, or a pure 12 digit number:

```regex
\d{9}[VX]|\d{12}
```

Sample Java script:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
    "923456789V",
    "200551789012",
    "123INVALID"});
for (String val : list) {
    if (val.matches("\\d{9}[VX]|\\d{12}")) {
        System.out.println(val + " => VALID");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(val + " => INVALID");
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
923456789V => VALID
200551789012 => VALID
123INVALID => INVALID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with below regex:

```
^(\d{9}(X|V)|\d{12})$
```

**Demo Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{9}(X|V)|\\d{12})$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("444444444v");
    boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
    if(matchFound) {
      System.out.println("Match found");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Match not found");
    }
  }
```

**Output:** Match found

If you want to make it case sensitive remove strong `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` parameter.